# How to test is an "If loop" in UnitTestcase Xunit C#

Tags: c#, xunit

I have a Rest API endpoint. And I want to check if the loop is executing in the Unit test case Following is my code. But **if (days > 365)** part I not covered in my unit test case. how to include that part in the unit test case

```
[HttpPost, Route("v1/test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(Request request)
        {
           
            var days = (request.ToDate - request.FromDate).TotalDays;
            var today = new MonthMap(request.ToDate.UtcDateTime.Month, request.ToDate.UtcDateTime.Day);
            var fromDay = new MonthMap(request.FromDate.UtcDateTime.Month, request.FromDate.UtcDateTime.Day);

            if (days > 365)
            {
                fromDay = new MonthMap(1, 1);
                today = new MonthMap(12, 31);
            }

            var query = new Query
            {
                ToDay = today,
                FromDay = fromDay
            };

            var today = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var results = await _valueService.GetResult(query, today);

            return new OkObjectResult(results);
        }
    }
    public MonthMap(int month, int day)
        {
            if (month > 12 || month < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(" number between 1 and 12");
            }
            if (day < 1 || day > 31)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("number between 1 and 31");
            }
            Day = day;
            Month = month;

Unittest

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test_Run_When_Day_Greater_Than_365()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new Request 
        {
            FromDate = new DateTimeOffset(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero),
            ToDate = new DateTimeOffset(2022, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero),
        };
    
        var mockValueService = new Mock<IValueService>();
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<ReportsController>>();
        var controller = new ReportsController(mockValueService .Object, mockLogger.Object);
    
        mockValueService .Setup(x => x.GetResult(It.IsAny<Query>(),It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new List<MonthLyDataModel>
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "1" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "2" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "3" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "4" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "5" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "6" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "7" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "8" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "9" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "10" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "11" },
            {new IresultModel{ Id = "1", Result= "CO1", Month= "12" },
            });
    
        // Act
        var result = await controller. Run(request);
    
      Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
      var resultObject = (OkObjectResult)result;
      var resultJson = (List<MonthLyDataModel>)resultObject.Value;
      Assert.Equal(resultJson.Count, 12);
    }
```

My unit test is not actually covered the loop. Its just counting only the dummy data. Is it possible to check this part of code?. If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Use a `ToDate` more than a year after the `FromDate`?

Comment: Or use dates in a leap year like 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31?

Comment: noneed to consider leapyear

Comment: just consider todate more than fromdate

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood. I tought you want to adapt the test in such a way that the `(days > 365)`  condition is `true`. Maybe you could [edit] your question to make it clearer what you are actually asking.